# How to verify if a servlet processing is really doing non-blocking io?

Tags: java, http, servlets, nonblocking, jakarta-ee

I am trying to receive an http request using non-blocking io, then make another http request to another server using non-blocking io, and return some response, here is the code for my servlet:

```
package learn;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.ReadListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.WriteListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.InvocationCallback;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/async"}, asyncSupported = true)
public class AsyncProcessing extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -535924906221872329L;
    
    public CompletableFuture<String> readRequestAsync(final HttpServletRequest req) {       
        
        final CompletableFuture<String> request = new CompletableFuture<>();
        final StringBuilder httpRequestData = new StringBuilder();
        try (ServletInputStream inputStream = req.getInputStream()){                        
            inputStream.setReadListener(new ReadListener() {
                final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4*1024;
                final byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    request.completeExceptionally(t);
                }
                
                @Override
                public void onDataAvailable() {
                    if(inputStream.isFinished()) return;
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("onDataAvailable: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    try {
                        while(inputStream.isReady()) {
                          int length = inputStream.read(buffer);                      
                          httpRequestData.append(new String(buffer, 0, length));
                       }
                    } catch (IOException ex) { 
                        request.completeExceptionally(ex);
                    }
                }
                
                @Override
                public void onAllDataRead() throws IOException {
                    try {
                        request.complete(httpRequestData.toString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        request.completeExceptionally(e);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            request.completeExceptionally(e);
        }                               
        
        return request;
    }
    
    
    
    private Client createAsyncHttpClient() {
        ResteasyClientBuilder restEasyClientBuilder = (ResteasyClientBuilder)ClientBuilder.newBuilder();

        return restEasyClientBuilder.useAsyncHttpEngine().connectTimeout(640, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    }
    
    public CompletableFuture<Response>  process(String httpRequest){        
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("process: " + Thread.currentThread());
        
        CompletableFuture<Response> futureResponse = new CompletableFuture<>();
        
        Client client = createAsyncHttpClient();
        client.target("http://localhost:3000").request().async().get(new InvocationCallback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(Response response) {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("completed: " + Thread.currentThread());
                futureResponse.complete(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println(throwable);
                futureResponse.completeExceptionally(throwable);
            }
        });
        
        return futureResponse;
    }
    
    public CompletableFuture<Integer> outputResponseAsync(Response httpResponseData, HttpServletResponse resp){
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("outputResponseAsync: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        
        CompletableFuture<Integer> total = new CompletableFuture<>();
        try (ServletOutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream()){            
            outputStream.setWriteListener(new WriteListener() {             
                
                @Override
                public void onWritePossible() throws IOException {
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("onWritePossible: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());                                 
                    
                    outputStream.print(httpResponseData.getStatus());
                    total.complete(httpResponseData.getLength());
                }
                
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    System.out.println(t);
                    total.completeExceptionally(t);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            total.completeExceptionally(e);
        }
        
        return total;
    }
        
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("doGet: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        final AsyncContext asyncContext = req.startAsync();
        readRequestAsync(req)
            .thenCompose(this::process)
            .thenCompose(httpResponseData -> outputResponseAsync(httpResponseData, resp))       
            .thenAccept(a -> asyncContext.complete());
    }
}
```

The server at http://localhost:3000 is an http server written in node which just returns a response after 27 seconds, i would like to make a request to the node server and while this request is being processed i would want to make another http request to the servlet to see if the same thread is being used. Currently i'm trying to use payara 5.194 to do this but even if i set the two thread pools to have one thread the app server seems to create another threads. So, i would like to know from your knowledge if this servlet is really doing non-blocking io and not blocking at any time, also it would be amazing if i could do some experiment to ensure this. I think it's important to point out that the class ServletInputStream is a subclass of InputStream, so i really don't know if this is non-blocking io. Thank you.

Comment: Misusing `ready()` here. You already know data is available because that's why you're in his method.

Comment: You are right, the algorithm to read data from the stream could be more elegant. I actually took it from: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/servlets013.html#sthref109  , and then i just modified it a little.

Comment: @user207421  Did you mean this line: int length = inputStream.read(buffer); ? Because i have just read the docs for the .read function and it says: This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown. Does it mean this method is blocking and should not be used here? Because if that is true the tutorial is incorrect.

Comment: I'm trying to use a combination of the inputStream.available() and the inputStream.readNBytes() , but then i found this on available doc: A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes.

I don't think it can cause any trouble because if i don't read all the bytes on one call of onDataAvailable i may read the rest on the next call. Am i correct?

Comment: There is `java.lang.management.ThreadInfo.getBlockedCount/getBlockedTime`. But, I guess that's not going to record if the thread is parked, and blocking probably happens more than you might think. Any kind of shared lock, which will presumably include [lazy] class loading.

Comment: I will try it out. On payara there is a http thread pool and another one called thread-pool-1, and i'm wondering if the threads from http thread pool just deliver the requests to the other pool, then this counter won't be very usefull. But it is some information. I also found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWZf62zJ3JE  maybe if i look into the rest easy code it can help me.

Comment: I have also found this project: http://undertow.io i'm gonna study its documentation it seems like they might be something in there.